# convert type int to array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, request

how to convert typeint to type array?
In fact the value q "'we stored in the database is like this a: 1: {i: 0; i: 30;} but when I do research I simply entered 30
I want to do this
request

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price = 30
```

instead of

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE price = "a: 1: {i: 0; i: 30;}"
```

Comment: Why in the world is the price stored as a serialized string in your database?

Comment: My guess would be, price was a dc2 type array like[ 'dollar' => int, 'penny' => int]  but yeah, that's just gonna be trouble